# How to make a contour ternary represents surface response with R

Tags: r, ggtern

I want to make a triangle plot represents the response surface for all possible combinations of `X`, `Y` and `Z` factors and the gradient area inside the triangle expresses the predicted distribution of the response variable `Gi`.

```
# Here are the data:
X <- rep(c(45,40,55,40,43,50,43,50,43,48), each = 3)
Y <- rep(c(15, 12,22,14,14,19,12,17,17,12 ), each = 3)
Z <- rep(c(15,22,12,12,19,14,14,17,12,17), each = 3)
Gi <- c(353,381,320,312,335,265,394,350,374,320,299,316,300,304,295,360,331,395,
351,280,342,299,303,279,374,364,419,306,290,315)
Ft <- data.frame (X, Y, Z)
# Fitted model:
require (compositions) # package "compositions"
model = lm(Gi ~ ilr (Ft) + I (ilr (Ft)^2) + I (ilr (Ft)^3) )
# Generate random compositional data of the factors X, Y, and Z
library(tmvtnorm)
corMat <- var(Ft)
dt3 <- rtmvnorm (n=500, mean = c(45.2, 15.4, 15.4), sigma = corMat, lower = c(10,5,5), upper = c(80,60,60))
# Predict Gi using the model
pGi <- predict (model, list (Ft = dt3) )
pdt <- cbind (dt3, pGi) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  rename (X = V1, Y = V2, Z = V3)
```

With the model and predicted data, is it possible to express the estimated `pGi` as gradient surface in the triangle to get the output like the example enclosed? I have tried with `ggtern` below, but the output ternary plot is not what I want.

```
ggtern(data = pdt, aes(x = X, y = Y, z = Z, value = pGi)) +
  stat_interpolate_tern(geom="polygon",
                        formula = value ~ x+y, 
                        method = lm,
                        aes(fill = ..level..), expand = 1) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="green", high="blue") +
  theme_gray () +
  theme ( tern.axis.arrow.show = T)
```

[image]

Comment: I fixed up a few things but (1) your code isn't reproducible (what is `corMat`?) (2) you've said "the output is not what you want" - can you say how/why?

Comment: Thanks Ben for fixing. I've added corMat. The output is not what I want because want to produce a plot look like the one attached but with my code, it provide somethings else. Also the distribution of gradient color representing the estimated Gi on the triangle is not logic with the fitted model. I am not sure if I explained well enough.